# How to read attributes and values in XML using Node Js

Tags: node.js, xml, soap

I used a SOAP API to get the response. And now I have a long XML response. I tried to convert XML into JSON and then to read. But, it couldn't work. Then I tried xml2js , xmldom and filterxml to read the attributes. But, it didn't work.

XML Response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI" />
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI" />
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>36465</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>4767547547745757</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>45757457547</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2020-04-29T12:13:28</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>63465653634ffghfghfghf</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">bmkfdkdgkdskmlskfsdfpskmfl</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <SessionCreateRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" version="1" status="Approved">
            <ConversationId>4767547547745757</ConversationId>
        </SessionCreateRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

**Update

As I told I tried to convert XML into JSON using xml2jsn. And it gave me the complete json response. But, I can't go for a attribute that I want because of these symbols, -(dash) and :(colon).

I just want to get " wsse:BinarySecurityToken " value. Then how can go for the wsse:BinarySecurityToken ??

```
var parseString = parseStringReq.parseString;

parseString(SetSoapTokenRes, function (err, result) {
    let json_res = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
    // json_res = json_res.replace(':', '_') //output: 'A D C'
res.end(json_res.soap-env:Envelope);
});
```

Comment: are you trying to parse the response from client side or via terminal independently ?

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID - I created a API to get the result from web browser. Now I want to return only basekey with that API.

Comment: You need to select one of the approaches you tried. Show us exactly what you did, and tell us exactly how it failed, and then we can tell you what you did wrong. Telling us you tried everything, nothing worked, and can we suggest anything else is not a good way of approaching problem solving. (We need to see your mistakes. For example, perhaps you just haven't grokked namespaces.)

Comment: @MichaelKay - I updated the question. Can I Fix it ??

Comment: @Amithash converting the XML to JSON in order to access it seems a rather roundabout way of doing things. You're welcome to try it if you find it convenient, but I can't help you with it.

Comment: @MichaelKay - If this is not a good way, what can I do to read XML attributes ??

Comment: The conventional way would be to build an XML DOM and navigate the DOM.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Okay , I will try that out. Thank U !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to make it simpler by transforming XML to JSOn with only the data you are interested in, you can use [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro) and do this:

```
const { ready, transform } = require('camaro')

const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI" />
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI" />
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>36465</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>4767547547745757</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>45757457547</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2020-04-29T12:13:28</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>63465653634ffghfghfghf</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">bmkfdkdgkdskmlskfsdfpskmfl</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <SessionCreateRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" version="1" status="Approved">
            <ConversationId>4767547547745757</ConversationId>
        </SessionCreateRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
`
const template = {
    token: 'soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:BinarySecurityToken',
    conversationId: 'soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/SessionCreateRS/ConversationId'
}

;(async function () {
    const result = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(result)
})()
```

the template is just an example. you can add more fields if you want. Accessing `token` is simply `result.token`

example output

```js
{
  token: 'bmkfdkdgkdskmlskfsdfpskmfl',
  conversationId: '4767547547745757'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like your trying to get the result incorrectly. Instead of `json_res.soap-env:Envelope` try `json_res['soap-env:Envelope']` it maybe escaping because of the special character.

Comment: I tried with this ```res.end(json_res['soap-env:Envelope']);```. But, nothing happened. No response or errors. Then I added another one like this ```res.end(json_res['soap-env:Envelope']['soap-env:Header']);``` And I got this error - ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'soap-env:Header' of undefined```. What can I do ??

Comment: is var `parseStringReq` initialized

Comment: yes, ```var parseStringReq = require('xml2js');``` What is the problem ??

Comment: It’s wasn’t included in your code sample and wanted to make sure you initialized the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I converted XML into JSON using xml2js package. And used below code to read attributes as I want.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

parser.parseString(xml_response, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('here is the eror: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        console.log(["soap-env:Envelope"]["soap-env:Header"][0]["token"]); 
    }
});
```